# SSIS Execute SQL Task returns empty result set

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis-2008

I have an Execute SQL Task in the control flow that I've made in SSIS.
When a run the same script on the database where it connects to, the select statement returns a result set, but when I run it via the execute SQL task, it returns an empty set.

I have configured the SSIS package pointing to the database where I ran the SQL script.

The task returns no error or it didn't mention about failed connection in the database.

What else could be the culprit?

Additional info:

Connection Type: OLE DB

Result Set: Full result set

SQLSourceType: Direct input

SQL Statement: `SELECT P.ID, P.Name from Processes P WHERE P.hasFlag = 'Y'`

Bypass Prepare: True

Comment: I would verify the connection is good. It sounds to me like you have missed something. Maybe post the code.

Comment: I have added information. Do you have an idea if there is a limit on the number of rows it returns?

Comment: Have you configured a result set on the 'Result Set' tab?

Comment: Hi @ChrisMack, yes I did. I configured it to Full Result Set

Comment: This would be in the 'General' tab (ResultSet = Full result set)? But did you configure this to be written to a variable in the 'Result Set' tab? Otherwise you'd just be selecting the data but doing nothing with it. A full result set needs to go into an Object variable.

Comment: The Result Name is set to 0 and Variable Name assigned to it has object data type

Comment: How are you checking for results after you have written to the variable? Is the error there?

Comment: I pass it to a for loop, there is no error tho.

Comment: I would check the way your loop is configured (can you provide details?) I can't see any other possible cause.